# like command in teradata or what to use to get all files

Tags: sql, sql-like, teradata-sql-assistant

When I run my command below it only pulls 1 file when there should be multiple files what do I have wrong ?

select srvc_dt as Service_Date_Month,emr_pract_src_cd as Practice,SRC_MEASR_DESC as Source_Measure,file_nm as FileName
,rec_status as Record_Status,rec_type as Population,src_lob_cd as Source_Lineofbusiness
from  test_TAB
where file_nm like ('%Novant%')
and src_measr_desc in ('CDC_A1C','CBP')
---and src_measr_desc in ('%cdc_a1c%','%cbp%')
and srvc_dt between date '2022-01-01' and date '2022-12-31'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I tried using "Like" "=" "in" for file_nm but it is still just pulling 1 file

Comment: Without some sample data it's hard to say. It looks like you may have originally been looking for the condition `src_measr_desc like any ('%cdc_a1c%','%cbp%')`